# Convert checkboxes as binary values ( '0' for unchecked, '1' for checked) to json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a HTML table which have checkboxes. I want these whole table into JSON data with checkboxes as binary values '0' for unchecked and '1' for checked.

HTML CODE:

```
<table id="sem3_table" class="w3-table w3-card w3-table-all w3-hoverable">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>PRN NO.</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Discrete Maths</th>
  <th>ECCF</th>
  <th>Data Structures</th>
  <th>DLDA</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
  <td>1234568</td>
  <td>Smith</td>
  <td><input class="w3-check jill" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td><input class="w3-check jill" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td><input class="w3-check jill" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td><input id="select-all" class="w3-check" type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>7894562</td>
  <td>Jackson</td>
  <td><input class="w3-check" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td><input class="w3-check" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td><input class="w3-check" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td><input class="w3-check" type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>Johnson</td>
    <td><input class="w3-check" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input class="w3-check" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input class="w3-check" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input class="w3-check" type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'v done this so far, not getting any idea how to do with checkboxes.

**JAVASCRIPT CODE FOR JSON:**

```
function html2json() {
    var json = '{';
    var otArr = [];
    var tbl2 = $('#sem3_table').each(function(e) {
    x = $(this).children();
    var itArr = [];
    x.each(function() {
       itArr.push('"' + $(this).text() + '"');   
    });
    otArr.push('"' + e + '": {' + itArr.join(',') + '}');
 })
 json += otArr.join(",") + '}'
 return json;
}
```

The output should be:

```
"0" : {
    "PRN NO" : "12345",
    "NAME" :   "XYZ",
    "DISCRETE MATHS" : "0",             //0=> unchecked, 1=> checked
    "ECCf" : "1",
    "Data structures" : "1",
    "DLDA"  : "0"    
 },

"1" : {
      //same//

 }
```

Comment: Checkboxes need a `value` attribute so that when one becomes checked it is apparent what the check represents. Having a value of `0` or `1` is meaningless without a value to go with it.

Comment: Throw out the html2json code - it is not worth saving the “json generation” it contains. Try again, using JSON.stringify (note how this conversion transforms an entire JS object graph, including whatever values have been mapped).

Comment: heck don't even do that: just put that table in a form, and create a FormData object using new FormData(yourFormElement). Why would you bother with JSON when there's a free serialization approach already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never build JSON format through string concatenation. Build the object/array first, and when you have collected all data into it, only then convert to JSON using `JSON.stringify`.

Here is how that could work:

```js
function html2json() {
    var props = $.map($('#sem3_table th'), function(th) {
        return $(th).text();
    });
    return JSON.stringify($('#sem3_table tr').slice(1).map(function() {
        var obj = {};
        $(this).children().each(function(i) {
            var value = +$("input", this).prop("checked"); 
            obj[props[i]] = isNaN(value) ? $(this).text() : value;
        });
        return obj;
    }).get(), null, 2);
}

$("button").click(function() {
    const json = html2json();
    console.log(json);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Produce JSON</button>
<table id="sem3_table" class="w3-table w3-card w3-table-all w3-hoverable">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>PRN NO.</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Discrete Maths</th>
  <th>ECCF</th>
  <th>Data Structures</th>
  <th>DLDA</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
  <td>1234568</td>
  <td>Smith</td>
  <td><input class="w3-check jill" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td><input class="w3-check jill" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td><input class="w3-check jill" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td><input id="select-all" class="w3-check" type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>7894562</td>
  <td>Jackson</td>
  <td><input class="w3-check" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td><input class="w3-check" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td><input class="w3-check" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td><input class="w3-check" type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>Johnson</td>
    <td><input class="w3-check" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input class="w3-check" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input class="w3-check" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input class="w3-check" type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```